# Use of "is_numeric" to safely read file that only contains a zero ("0")?

Tags: php

In my file read function, `if($theData = @fread($fh, filesize($myFile))` was returning false if the target failed contained nothing but a zero, so I added a check for integer (`is_numeric`). Is this safe?

```
function readfilecontents($myFile)
{
    if($fh = @fopen($myFile, 'r'))
    {
        $theData = @fread($fh, filesize($myFile));
        if($theData || is_numeric($theData))
        {
            if(@fclose($fh))
            {
                return $theData;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: if ($theData !== FALSE)

Comment: @MarkBaker Post as answer with brief explanation so this can be closed.

Comment: note: that `fclose` should be before the check (so you always execute it)...

Comment: Even better: use file_get_contents($myFile) instead of reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not safe - e.g. if you're reading an empty file, your function will return false instead of an empty string. But there is no need for a function like this as [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/file_get_contents) does the exact same thing (just faster).